# How to pass attirbute value to angular 2.0 component from html?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

In Polymer I can create custom Polymer element and set any of its properties via html like so

settings string attribute or even object.

How to do that in angular 2.0?

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ItemsPipe} from './pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'json-schema-form',
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: 'app/json-schema-form.html',
    pipes: [ItemsPipe],
    inputs: [
        'foo:foo',
    ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(http_: Http) {
        console.log('constructor invoked');
        this.http = http_;
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('init invoked');
        console.log(this.foo);
        this.http.get(this.foo)
        .subscribe(resp => this.schema = resp.json());
    }
    //foo = 'test-hyper-schema.json'

    @Input() foo;
    http = {};

    schema = {
        properties: {
            id: {
                type: 'number',
                title: 'Resource id',
            }
        },
    };
    entity = {};
    toInputType = function(schemaType) {
        var mapping = {
            string: 'text',
            number: 'number',
            integer: 'number',
        };
        return mapping[schemaType];
    }

    props = function () {
        return Object.keys(this.schema.properties);
    };
}
```

Here is index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
    <title>Angular experiments</title>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <json-schema-form foo="test-hyper-schema.json">
      Loading...
    </json-schema-form>

    <!--<json-schema-form >-->
      <!--Loading...-->
    <!--</json-schema-form>-->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lots of code but it's unclear to me what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Input()` currently doesn't work on the root component (`AppComponent`).

Comment: I'll try put it in another component. If this would work I would accept your answer.

Comment: One more thing. The point of this component is to create reusable widget. How would other people use it, if it wouldn't work in root component?

Comment: Reusable Angular components are only usable within other Angular components, therefore this shouldn't be a problem otherwise it's a "standalone" Angular application where you can have more than one within one page but that's unusual.